# SSL context service in apache nifi

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

Good morning everyone
I made an apache Nifi project where I use GetHttp and PostHttp. The thing is that an error is occurring: [image: Error capture] 
I looked for it on google but I did not understand exactly what to do? what is SSL cert? how to add it?
[image: Configure Controller Service]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to create and configure an SSLContextService for the processor to use so that it can establish trust with the certificate being presented by the DataSift service. curl works because it is tying into the default system truststore for you.

To provide a similar experience as curl on the command line, you will need to configure the truststore properties for your SSL Context Service instance with:

1. Truststore Filename:

the cacerts file from your Java installation
If $JAVA_HOME Is set on your system, it should help point you in the right direction. If not, the location of cacerts varies depending on environment, but is approximately the following for their respective OS

- OS X:
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
- Windows: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts
- Linux: /usr/lib/jvm/java-/jre/lib/security/cacerts -- You
  can additionally use $(readlink -f $(which java))

  2. Truststore Type:JKS
  3. Truststore Password: The default password of "changeit" if you are using the default Java keystore

**When this controller service is created and enabled, the associated GetHTTP will need to be updated to reference it.**

Comment: I my case for MacOS I've found cacert under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`

Answer (score 1):

I was using Consume_Kafka_2_0 to consume messages, then I need to setup SSL Context Service.

You can provide Trust store details to consume messages for SSL secured.

Trust Store File name-> It is system dependent for me it is "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security", if open JDK is not installed you need to install that first.

Steps:

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk  
brew install adoptopenjdk11 --cask  
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Password: by default it is "changeit"
type: JKS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create and configure your ssl context service, then enable it .

[image]

Comment: yeah exactly! but I didn't understand how to fill those blanks (KeyStore filename ...)