# Local Setup Nifi needs to consume Kafka messages from my client server . What are configuration steps involved?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-nifi, jaas

I am using Nifi with Local setup .
I am using 'consumeKafka' Processor

In configuration I am specifying

Kafka broker : Client_specified_broker ,
Security Protocol : SASL_SSL ,
SASL Mechanism : Plain ,
Username : SSL username ,
Password : SSL password ,
SSL Context Service : StandardSSLContextService ,
Topic : Topic From which data is consumed ,
Group_id : test

I was getting

> SSL Context validated against '0x74-04......' id is invalid as the controller service with this Id is disabled

To resolve this
1 . I have enabled Controller service and followed steps as in
[SSL context service in apache nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633649/ssl-context-service-in-apache-nifi)
2 . created a jaas.config file and given its path in bootstrap.config

I am unable to fetch the data yet . Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Just enable the controller service...

Comment: @daggett ,
I have enabled the controller service . I ve choosen SSLCONTEXTSERVICE and followed the same steps as in 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633649/ssl-context-service-in-apache-nifi

I am not getting any error but could not fetch the data
Any Idea  if  someother config settings to be taken care of?

Comment: If you're not getting any error then maybe the config of topic and groupid is incorrect?